# How to send an email address through eBay

Tags: email, ebay

Ebay let's you message sellers and buyers but it doesn't let you include an email address in your message.

The warning prompt:

> [image: ebay - no emails]

`johndoe at gmail dot come` doesn't work either.

Presumably they do this to prevent users from circumventing their checkout process. But I'm just trying to get in touch with the guy on the other end of the transaction.

Is there any way to communicate email addresses via eBay message?

Comment: is there a reason you need to include an email address? Doesn't ebay's messaging system serve the purpose if you want to get in touch with the other person?

Comment: From ebay account,you cant forward the mail,if you forward it would go to your registered email id they are preventing the email sending option to other user from their account so if the seller cant be reached through the email.you can contact email support with the seller id to register your complaint

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't really recommend contacting people outside of eBay—the restrictions are there for a reason! :)

However, you could use http://scr.im or  http://tinymailto.com/ which converts your email in to a standard HTTP URL.

e.g.

> **from this:** myname.longlastname@my.university.example.net
>
> **to this:** http://tinymailto.com/abcd

They also offer the ability to have a vanity URL rather than a randomly generated one.

Answer (score 6):

eBay Messages allows you to attach images so just write your email address in paint and then attach it.

Comment: Genius - don't know why this is downvoted

Comment: Great approach. I did it in Word with bigger font for better readability.

Answer (score 2):

Write your email backward says [smashgods.com](http://smashgods.com/2013/10/28/ebay-your-message-wasnt-sent-because-it-included-an-email-address/):

> moc.ilamtoh@nhoj

Another [idea](http://forums.anandtech.com/showpost.php?p=35192204&postcount=23):

> ig-pay atin-lay? omeone-say otmail-hay om-cay?

Or, direct the person to a contact form on your website.

Answer (score 2):

I added my email address to a notepad file and uploaded to a Dropbox folder then shared the Dropbox folder link. That worked!

Answer (score 1):

Write your email on a piece of paper, take a photo with your phone then send that on the ebay message

Answer (score -2):

You can use [www.channelreply.com](http://www.channelreply.com) to forward messages into zendesk and post replies there.  Works for Amazon as well.